# Have batch file read the same random number?

Tags: batch-file

Need help here, I'm trying to make my batch file print a random number, and then repeat that random number multiple times, here's what I want.

```
echo Your ID is: %RANDOM%
echo Again, your ID is: %RANDOM%
```

Is there anyway to have the two randoms match each other and print the same number? But be different everytime I open the .bat?

Comment: assign it to a variable once and use this variable several times.

Comment: Don't use %RANDOM% as an Id without keeping a record of all the Id's you've handed with this method.  There is always a 1/32k chance that it will return the same number to two different users/processes.

Comment: You can do what you want like this, `Set "UserID=%RANDOM%"`, then you can just use `%UserID%` as and when required. Please  take account of the previous comment too, as well as noting that the generated number can be any integer from 0  up to 32767 inclusive, so you may wish to perform some sort of additional work if you want it to be less random than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set random2=%RANDOM%
echo Your ID is: %random2%
echo Again, Your ID is: %random2%
```

basically, `set random2=%RANDOM%` sets a variable named "random2" to said random number. then, `echo Your ID is: %random2%` will print correctly, along with the second `echo`.
let's say the random number is `10082`. the code states it as:

```
Your ID is: 10082
Again, Your ID is: 10082
```

Comment: You only needed a relatively small fix, `set random2=%RANDOM%` as opposed to `set random2 = %RANDOM%`. Your version created a variable `%random2 %` with a numeric value beginning with a space. Incidentally, you added a space after `%random%` in your new code, so your returned value will also have that space character after the last digit too.